Error SQL Server [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file
Estoy intentando copiar y pasar un archivo de un servidor a otro con xp_cmdshell pero muestra el error
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file
NULL

El comando es el siguiente
DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
SET @cmd ='bcp "select * from Pruebas.dbo.Nombres" queryout "\\192.168.7.15\d$\Archivos\Carga.txt" -T -S SPRUEBAS -c -t \t'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

cuando ejecuto el comando con powershell como administrador si me deja:
bcp "select * from Pruebas.dbo.Nombres" queryout "\\192.168.7.15\d$\Archivos\Carga.txt" -T -S SPRUEBAS -c -t \t


powershell no tiene nada que ver en esto, xp_cmdshell ejecuta cmd.exe, por otro lado, lo ejecuta con el usuario que corre el motor de base de datos, por tanto el hecho de que corra como administrador es irrelevante. Lo que puede estar ocurriendo es que el usuario en el que corre el servicio de base de datos no tiene permisos suficientes, y hasta donde recuerdo, no los va a tener a recursos de red, pues es un usuario local del equipo del servidor de base de datos, y no un usuario de dominio u otro tipo que pueda referenciarse remotamente.
